# How to get this form data without using browser?

Tags: python, web-services, autologin

Im new to python and figured that best way to learn is by practice, this is my first project.

So there is this fantasy football website. My goal is to create script which logins to site, automatically creates preselected team and submits it.

I have managed to get to submitting team part.

When I add a team member this data gets sent to server:

https://i.gyazo.com/e7e6f82ca91e19a08d1522b93a55719b.png

When I press save this list this data gets sent:

https://i.gyazo.com/546d49d1f132eabc5e6f659acf7c929e.png

Code:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as c:
    gameurl = 'here is link where data is sent'
    BPL = ['5388', '5596', '5481', '5587', 
    '5585', '5514', '5099', '5249', '5566', '5501', '5357']
    GID = '168'
    UDID = '0'
    ACT = 'draft'
    ACT2 = 'save_draft'
    SIGN = '18852c5f48a94bf3ee58057ff5c016af'

    # eleven of those with different BPL since 11 players needed:
    c.get(gameurl)
    game_data = dict(player_id = BPL[0], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)

    # now I need to submit my list of selected players:
    game_data_save = dict( action = ACT2, id = GID, user_draft_id = UDID, sign = SIGN)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data_save)
```

This code works pretty fine, but the problem is, that 'SIGN' is unique for each individual game and I have no idea how to get this data without using Chromes inspect option.

How can I get this data simply running python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you said you can find it using devtools I'm assuming `SIGN` is written somewhere in the DOM.
In that case you can use `requests.get().text` to get the HTML of the page and parse it with a tool like [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)

Comment: Ok, but thing is I get 'SIGN' data in source code only after I click to save empty list, soo, how do I simulate a click on a button inside code?

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks for leading on to solution. Solved by posting all data without 'SIGN' and in return I got 'SIGN' in html.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by posting all data without 'SIGN' and in return I got 'SIGN' in html.